# CSS transition bug when using viewport units in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: css, internet-explorer, css-transitions, css-transforms, viewport-units

I have a css transition that is triggered by changing an attribute with JQuery/JS.
It works nicely, except in internet explorer (11).

I have no idea what's going on here, any ideas?

Edit: the problem seems to be caused by using viewport units. It works fine when using any other type of unit. The second snippet shows a working example.

```js
$('#click').click(function() {
var data_test = $('#container').attr('data-test');
if(data_test == 'one') $('#container').attr('data-test', 'two');
else $('#container').attr('data-test', 'one');
});
```

```css
#container {
position: relative;
width: 100%; height: 100px;
}

#container > div {
position: absolute;
right: 1vw;
font-size: 1em;
top: 0.1em;
transition: all 1s;
}

#container[data-test="one"] > div {
transform: translate(-8vw, 15vh);
font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" data-test="one"><div>some text</div></div>

  <div id="click">click</div>
```

```js
$('#click').click(function() {
var data_test = $('#container').attr('data-test');
if(data_test == 'one') $('#container').attr('data-test', 'two');
else $('#container').attr('data-test', 'one');
});
```

```css
#container {
position: relative;
width: 100%; height: 100px;
}

#container > div {
position: absolute;
right: 1vw;
font-size: 1em;
top: 0.1em;
transition: all 1s;
}

#container[data-test="one"] > div {
transform: translate(-4em, 4em);
font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" data-test="one"><div>some text</div></div>

  <div id="click">click</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently you need to set transform-origin in Internet Explorer. See the snippet. Note that you also need to transition transform-origin.

Thanks to cewn for helping me on my way to find the answer.

```js
$('#click').click(function() {
var data_test = $('#container').attr('data-test');
if(data_test == 'one') $('#container').attr('data-test', 'two');
else $('#container').attr('data-test', 'one');
});
```

```css
#container {
position: relative;
width: 100%; height: 100px;
}

#container > div {
position: absolute;
right: 1vw;
font-size: 1em;
top: 0.1em;
transform-origin: -8vw 15vh;
transform: translate(0vw, 0vh);
transition: all 1s;
}

#container[data-test="one"] > div {
transform-origin: 0vw 0vh;
transform: translate(-8vw, 15vh);
font-size: 1.3em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="container" data-test="one"><div>some text</div></div>

  <div id="click">click</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Transitioning shouldn’t be done on top, right, bottom or left anymore. For best performance use **transform: translateY(value); or transform: translateX(value);**. Remove the top props and transform those elements.
Repaints are probably messing it up. Let me know if it works ;-)

Comment: Hmm, there is a similar problem, although it works better. The animated element still jumps outside of view first. I'll add a snippet in original post.
Should I use transform in the initial css too, instead of top/right?

Comment: Using transform in the initial css doesn't seem to make a difference, so there's still something else going on in IE11.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why, but IE11 messes it up while using viewport units, I've tried it myself by settings the transform value for example to transform: translate(-8rem, 15rem); which seems to solve the problem.

Comment: You're right! Thanks! Although it's kind of important for me to use viewport units in this case :( I'll edit my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar problem when experimenting with a new navigation menu that used *transform* to rotate a DIV.  Some of DIVs expand as they rotate, so I was already setting *transform-origin* to ensure that they rotate about the original centre.  I'm using viewport units for sizing.  It worked in every browser apart from Internet Explorer.

I know it's a "bodge", but, having read here that IE doesn't like viewport units, a quick fix for me was to change *transform-origin: 5vw 5vw* to *transform-origin: calc(5vw) calc(5vw)* - the page now looks the same in IE as it does in other browsers.